# Exposing an USB device directly to a Virtualbox guest

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have an virtualBox VM with a windows guest system (Windows XP 32Bit). The Host is also a Windows (Windows 7 64Bit).

Normally I just want to use known usb devices (which are known by my host and have drivers installed there) in my guest system.

But this time I want to use an usb device which drivers are not installed on my host. I want to use it directly in my guest VM without installing it on my host.

At the moment I can only "see" the installed USB devices in my guest system.

Do you know how I can route my usb device directly to my guest?

Maybe I just missed something in the VM settings. I hope you have an advice for me. Thanks.